# How to configure a Dockerized GitLab CE on Ubuntu which is proxied with HTTPS by Apache2?

Tags: docker, gitlab, apache2.4, gitlab-ce

I am trying to configure my docker GitLab CE (latest) instance that works with an integrated letsnecrypt that is part of the docker, in order to authenticate it as HTTPS under a sub-domain that is proxied by an Apache 2.4.

The reason i want it to go through Apache is that In this environment there is a web page running which claims port 80, 443 etc. So, in order for me to have both, i have mapped docker's ports to 443:444 and 80:3000.

And via apache's virtual host naming i have the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost domain.com:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost gitlab.domain.com:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass        "/" "http://public-ip:3000/"
        ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://public-ip:3000/"
        ServerName gitlab.domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost gitlab.domain.com:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
        RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass        "/" "http://public-ip:3000/"
        ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://public-ip:3000/"
        ServerName gitlab.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

What do you think is the best approach?